# Can I connect to a Microsoft SQL Server with MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql-workbench

Is it possible for me to connect to a MSSQL database server with MySQL Workbench?

Comment: Ummm... MSSQL is not MySQL...

Comment: mysql workbench is for mysql. for Microsoft sql server i use management studio on PC, not sure about Mac.

Answer (score 14):

You cannot use MySQL Workbench as a Microsoft SQL Server client.

But technically speaking, yes, you can connect to a Microsoft SQL Server database using ODBC if you are using the database migration wizard.

Source: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-migration-wizard-connection.html

Comment: I would recommend using SQL Server Management Studio, DBeaver or Azure Data Studio.